# How to use auto generated Assembly.XmlSerializers.dll created by Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have my project creating an auto generated Assembly.XmlSerializers.dll
From what I've read up this is used to improve performance.

Do I need to alter my project in anyway in order for the CLR to use the .dll or does it automatically get used if it exists in the same directory as my assembly.

Thanks

Comment: No, XML serialization uses them automatically.  It will first search for the assembly, if not found then it will run the C# compiler to build one on-the-fly, that's expensive.

Comment: @HansPassant Prashu has provided a link which indicates that the precompled assembly needs to be added as a reference to the project and not just placed in the same directory.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/386/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto generated serializes will reduce the performance. Better to go with Pre-generated XmlSerializers to Increase Performance. Using sgen or xgen generate the assembly at build time.

eg: `Sgen.exe /t:MyType /a:MyAssembly.dll`

generated serializer assembly MyAssembly.XmlSerializers.dll should be added as reference to project or add it in GAC.

Comment: Your answer and @Hans Passant's answers are conflicting. Do you have any source references I can lookup?